# using tikz package on texstudio

Tags: tikz-pgf

OKKKK this tikz package is driving me crazy !! it's been hours i am surfing the net to resolve an issue i have when i try to compile a simple code

```
\documentclass{article} % say
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
We are working on
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);
\draw (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}.
\end{document}
```

i get numerous errors starting with this:

Extra \fi. \begin

Undefined control sequence. \draw

Comment: your example runs without error. Show your full log

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eR4Z.png

Comment: Sounds like a broken or incomplete installation … What is the **first** error message?

Comment: apparently, the installation of my compiler was incomplete as Qrrbrbirlbel said. the example works fine now, thank you so much for the replies.